# WIFI phy/link speed is good (150Mbs) but tested transfer speed is very slow (10Mbs). Why?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers

This is a nightmare to search for due to the extremely common and misused terms; otherwise, I wouldn't waste anyone's time here.

I am running Windows 10, and I bought a new PCIe wireless card for one PC 2 days ago, I believe it was working at full speed at the time but I did no tests. It was only managing around 1~2Mb/s earlier today, which caused me to look into it.

Currently, I'm getting a max transfer speed of around 10~15Mb/s, be that an internal network file transfer or an online speedtest (another machine gets 55Mb/s over lan, and 31Mb/s over the internet). I'm getting full bars connected over AC, and, not that it is ever perfectly accurate, windows status shows a link speed of 135/135Mb/s. No issues on other machines. It is across the house, so it is getting -55db which isn't ideal but should be fine.

And, of course, there were no significant other network usages during testing. I'm in a location where I'm the only router in range, so there should be minimal outside interference.

No virus was found (I figured that a virus might be using bandwidth and then hiding it from windows).

I tried the driver from the manufacturer's site: [Ubit WiFi 6 AX 3000Mbps PCIe WiFi Card with BT](http://www.evisionde.com/ProDetail.aspx?ProId=80)

And I tried Intel's latest driver (they made the chip, and the driver is a bit newer), which is [found here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19351/windows-10-and-windows-11-wi-fi-drivers-for-intel-wireless-adapters.html).

I'm unsure what could cause this massive discrepancy in link and transfer speeds. Of course overhead will eat into that, but **I still expect to get 70% of link speed.... I'm getting 7%.**

(And yes, all numbers here are in Megabits)

All above numbers are on 2.4Ghz, forcing to 5Ghz dropped speeds to 1Mbps (which is to be expected due to the poor connection -85). Disabling the Bluetooth device (part of the same card) didn't impact anything.

Edit: I solved the issue by cutting the ceiling out in the basement and running a lan cable. Wifi sucks.

Comment: Tell us about the access point. Your first link doesn’t work

Comment: Fixed first link. Router is a DIR-882 .. not that I think the router can be causing an issue with a single machine.  Just incase, I set it as top prio in QOS to no change though.

Comment: I get -55db on my phone too (from the same room). The phone can still manage 50Mb/s file transfers. Which I'm fine with. 10 is a bit painful.

Comment: Sorry, 50Mbps on the phone (over wifi), 10Mbps on the problem PC (over wifi). I don't see how moving the pc closer would help .... -55db should be fine, it even shows as 5 bars in windows.

Comment: Did you try to connect the PC to the phone as hotspot? You can't exclude a wifi or antenna position problem without this kind of test. IMO.

Comment: I get higher speeds if i don't use this card. But i'm trying to diagnose this card.